# python socket error 10061 connection refused

Tags: python, sockets, connection

I cannot connect to tcp server made with python and socket library. I have the error 10061 (connection refused).

This error is not du to the firewall.
Indeed, I already checked that blocking the connections from outside causes error 10060 (timeout) in the client side, not the error 10061 (connection refused).

Below the client:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("10.22.6.110", 5460))
```

And now the server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("10.22.6.110", 5460))
s.listen(5)
print s.accept()
```

Do you have an idea of what could cause this problem?

Comment: are you sure about the port number? It sounds a little low.. binding to that port gives me: `socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address`

Comment: From SANS: Well Known Ports: 0 through 1023.
Registered Ports: 1024 through 49151.
Dynamic/Private : 49152 through 65535.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers